# Question about the Google Android Publisher API (500 error)

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-console, android-googleapiclient

Since the end of the last week, I encounter internal errors (status code : 500) when I use the Google API "Android Publisher". Indeed, I cannot create "edits" anymore.

API used :

```
POST https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/edits
```

First step : I can authenticate myself correctly and get a bearer.
Second Step : The API always answers the same response : 500 / backendError / Internal error encountered.

Piece of received payload using the package name :
com.decathlon.applicationtest1 or com.decathlon.applicationtest2

```
 {
   "response":{
      "config":{
         "url":"https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.decathlon.applicationtest2/edits",
         "method":"POST",
         "headers":{
            "x-goog-api-client":"gdcl/3.2.2 gl-node/14.13.0 auth/5.10.1",
            "Accept-Encoding":"gzip",
            "User-Agent":"google-api-nodejs-client/3.2.2 (gzip)",
            "Authorization":"Bearer ya29.c.Ko8B4QdsSkPiK202JiitK9Em_2q9id5VvKim3N1Lq8uS6o97RS6986ZmUsxfrlaXXXXXXXXvBSp5dQEiGRx87zA88JBdMN_fljlwXf0Eu6PH12yFIlKaN-nwggVgYHQX9_PxcFdB1PZxEeIkaWmYZgkQfzVTvUtMhhIUNLXXXXXX",
            "Accept":"application/json"
         }
      "data":{
         "error":{
            "code":500,
            "message":"Internal error encountered.",
            "errors":[
               {
                  "message":"Internal error encountered.",
                  "domain":"global",
                  "reason":"backendError"
               }
            ],
            "status":"INTERNAL"
         }
      }
    [...]
   "code":500,
   "errors":[
      {
         "message":"Internal error encountered.",
         "domain":"global",
         "reason":"backendError"
      }
   ]
}
```

I used the packagename com.oxylane.alarmesantivol or com.decathlon.vision and it worked correctly.

- Can you tell me what I can do ?
- Is there a limit in the number of edits created ?
- Is there a way to list all of them to check them ?

Thank you,

Comment: An internal error suggests an issue in Play's servers, so consider reaching out directly to Play developer support. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I contacted the Google support.

Comment: did you get any response?

Comment: It was fixed the day after I asked !

Comment: This 500 error has been making me **furious** recently! I've had it when publishing listings, and when publishing bundles. The only solution is waiting and retrying, often just hours later the error would disappear, only to pop up again a day later.